# PHP способ получения данных.HTTP заголовки.

Tags: php, http

Есть задача обрабатывать на пхп запросы вида:

```
POST /post.php HTTP 1/0
content-length: {размер}

{бинарные данные}
```

Возмножно ли такое и как на пхп получить сами данные? какие именно заголовки нужно добавить?

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: вобщем если совсем упростить) как отправить бинарные данные через http и получить их скриптом на php без использования файлов.
интересуют заголовки и переменная на php в которую попадут данные.
На данный момент отправляю файлами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

Comment: давно не имею дела с PHP и не помню почему, но лучше использовать

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

Нашел, цитата из php.net:

>the preferred method for accessing the raw POST data is php://input. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: @AlexWindHope, как я понял из вопроса, там одно поле / один бинарный файл грузится, поэтому mutlipart не потребуется. Хотя, вы правы, вариант годный.

Comment: Ну видимо про данную переменную я и пытался узнать) благодарю. теперь вопрос, заголовков из вопроса достаточно чтоб апач передал это скрипту? либо нужно еще что то?

Comment: `Content-Type` ещё укажите, а то по умолчанию будет считаться, что вы `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` грузите, а не бинарные данные.

Answer (score -1):

Я такое делал CURLом. Примеров на русском полно для текущей задачи

Для отправки файлов нужно посмотреть какие нужны заголовки и где указывать бинарную часть. Можно тоже загуглить, на русском тоже такое есть

Comment: вопрос в получении :)

Comment: причем тут курл?)